# c how does function receive variable length argument?

Tags: c, macros, variable-length

if I had a function receiving variable length argument

```
void print_arg_addr (int n, ...)
```

I can use these three macro to parse the argument

```
va_start(ap,v)
va_arg(ap,t)
va_end(ap)
```

In my understanding,

**va_start** lets **ap** point to second parameter,

**va_arg** move **ap** to next parameter,

**va_end** lets **ap** point to NULL.

so I use the snippet below to check my understanding,
but it turns out that ap does not change,
I expect ap will increment by 4 each time.

```
void print_arg_addr (int n, ...)
{
    int i;
    int val;
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl,n);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        val=va_arg(vl,int);
        printf ("ap:%p , %d\n",vl,val);
    }
    va_end(vl);
    printf ("ap:%p \n",vl);
}

int main() 
{
    print_arg_addr(5,1,2,3,4,5);
}
```

output:

```
ap:0x7ffc62fb9890 , 1
ap:0x7ffc62fb9890 , 2
ap:0x7ffc62fb9890 , 3
ap:0x7ffc62fb9890 , 4
ap:0x7ffc62fb9890 , 5
ap:0x7ffc62fb9890
```

Thank you!

Comment: What `va_list` is, is implementation defined. It can be anything, even not a pointer at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `va_list` (like your `vl`) is some [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) that you are not allowed to pass to `printf`. Its implementation is private to your compiler (and [processor architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture)), and related to the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention). Compile your code with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. You'll get warnings, and you have [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) so you should be very [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108).

In other words, consider `va_list`, `va_start`, `va_end` (and all [stdarg(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html) ...) as some *magic* provided by the compiler. That is why they are part of the C11 specification (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) and often implemented as compiler builtins.

If you need to understand the *internals* of `va_list` and friends (but *you should not* need that), dive inside your compiler (and study [your ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI)). Since [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) of millions of source code lines, you could spend many years studying it. In your case, I don't think it is worth the effort.

You might also look at the generated assembler code (a `.s` file), using `gcc -O -S -fverbose-asm`

<sup>Current calling conventions use processor registers. This is why understanding the details of variadic calls is complex. In the 1980s, arguments were pushed on the machine stack, and at that time `va_start` returned some pointer into the stack. Things are much more complex now, and you don't want to dive into that complexity.</sup>

Comment: Out of curiosity, what platform uses registers for vararg functions? All platforms I've seen (embedded mostly) just seem to give up and always use stack based calling conventions for vararg functions.

Comment: @user694733 The calling conventions on SYSV amd64 are exactly the same for varargs and normal functions. Quick look at arm64 and powerpc shows the same. In fact, I'm quite sure that it's the only reasonable way to make an ABI if you still want to be able to support pre-ANSI C or old code in general. Ancient code can fully function while having the prototype `int printf();` and missing declarations are just a warning not an error in most compilers. For those things to keep working an ABI can't expect the caller to do anything smart and all varargs work is done in the callee.